# How do I stop query results from splitting an individual row's data between columns?

Tags: php, mysql, css

I've performed a query from a mySQL database and the results are returned correctly. I have this formatted with responsive CSS columns - three on a desktop and as the screen width decreases, the number of columns decrease. EZ PZ. HOWEVER, I want all the results from a single row to stay together and not get split between the columns. What happens currently is that I may have a Category and Name at the end of a column and the Address and other info jumps to the top of the next column. Is there any way to keep the info for each row together?

I'm a total noob at PHP and CSS, so please feel free to critique everything so I can learn. EDIT: Added HTML

The PHP: (EDITED back to original since it was working better)

```
    <?php
        $mysqli = NEW MySQLi ( 'localhost', 'user', 'password', 'db' );

        $resultSet = $mysqli->query("
            SELECT Category, Name, Address, City, State, Zip, Phone, Website
            FROM Table
            WHERE ColumnName = 'SomeCity'
         ");

        if($resultSet->num_rows != 0) {

            while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
            {
            $Category = $rows['Category'];
            $Name = $rows['Name'];
            $Address = $rows['Address'];
            $City = $rows['City'];
            $State = $rows['State'];
            $Zip = $rows['Zip'];
            $Phone = $rows['Phone'];
            $Website = $rows['Website'];

        echo "<h1>$Category</h1><p>$Name<br>$Address $City $State $Zip<br>$Phone<br>$Website</p>";

        }
        }

        ?>
```

The CSS:

```
#listings {
  -webkit-columns: 3 200px;
     -moz-columns: 3 200px;
          columns: 3 200px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 3em;
     -moz-column-gap: 3em;
          column-gap: 3em;
  -webkit-column-rule: 1px dotted #ddd;
     -moz-column-rule: 1px dotted #ddd;
          column-rule: 1px dotted #ddd;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
       column-fill: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  listings {
    height: 350px;
  }
}
```

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TITLE</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body class="homepage">
        <div id="page-wrapper">

            <!-- Header -->
                <div id="header-wrapper">
                    <header id="header" class="container">

                        <!-- Logo -->
                            <div id="logo">
                                <h1><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" /></a></h1>
                            </div>

                        <!-- Nav -->
                            <nav id="nav">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                    <li class="current"><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>

                    </header>
                </div>

<!-- Main -->
    <div id="main-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
        <h3>Listings</h3>
            <div id="listings">

<?php require_once('my-php-listings.php'); ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- Footer -->

        </div>

<!-- Scripts -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may want to look at `implode()`.

Comment: I added this:    $array = array($Category1,$Name,$Address,$City,$State,$Zip,$Phone,$Website);
echo "<pre>".implode("\n",$array)."</pre>";
But it puts the address city state and zip all on a separate line. I could rewrite it, but it's still not fixing the problem of it separating the records between the columns.

Comment: Edit oyur post to add the new information.

Comment: Post your HTML. I'm having to make a lot of assumptions here but based on what you've said, your HTML view is pushing some of the results to the top of your box — most likely due to your listings box having a set height of 350px. If the content is "longer" than 350px, it has nowhere to go but up. One other quick note, if your "listings" boxes are being repeated, change them to a class rather than assigning it an ID.

Comment: Added a stripped back version of the HTML. I just did an includes php where I wanted it. I also took the 350px off the height, but I forgot to edit that on here. Didn't make a difference that I noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<pre>`, put each record in its own `<div>`. Remove your height of 350px from your CSS unless you know for fact that each record is no more than 350px tall. You can then assign it a class and even go as far as adding a unique identifier as you loop through the records if you need further control over one or more specific boxes.

Comment: I think making sure each record is in its own div is going to be the answer. I will try some other things and report back when I figure it out. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend wrapping each record in its own `<div>` and applying the style `display: inline-block`. This will ensure that the blocks do not wrap over columns.

If you're still having issues after making the above changes, try also applying the [break-inside CSS property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#break-inside) to the `<div>` record elements:

```
div.record-class {
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
              page-break-inside: avoid; /* Firefox */
                   break-inside: avoid; /* IE 10+ */
}
```